# how to overwrite config variable value from cmd using config module of nodejs

Tags: node.js, config

How to change or overwrite the variables of the default.json file of config module from cmd.

> Here is the default.json file

```
"test":"TEST1"
```

and I want to change the test variable value from the cmd but when I run this command in cmd then I show the value of test which is set in default.json, not that value which I provide in cmd command.

> Here is the command which I use for changing test value

```
$env:TEST="TEST_VALUE" node app.js
```

Please help me for solving this problem how can I do this from outside

Comment: please see my answer below. I believe it will do what you need.

Comment: @jremi okay i will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can do for Unix systems:

```
export test="Test1"
```

Use "set" for windows.

Comment: it give me this error in cmd 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: this is also not working, after this i run node app.js command and in app.js i was printing test value but it is not showing me the overwritten value of test, it is showing me the old value which is in default.json file.

Comment: You have to pick the value from environment first. If it doesn't exist then pick it from default json file. Use process.env.test to get it from environment.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you...

**default.json**

```
{
    "test":"TEST1"
}
```

**app.js**

```
DEFAULT_CONFIG = require('./default.json');
process.argv.forEach((arg,index)=>{
    if(arg.match('--test')){
        DEFAULT_CONFIG.test = process.argv[index+1] ? 
            process.argv[index+1] : 
            DEFAULT_CONFIG.test;
    }
})
console.log(`test is now set to ${DEFAULT_CONFIG.test}`);
```

**Command line**

```
foo@bar:~$ node app.js
test is now set to TEST1

foo@bar:~$ node app.js  --test TEST_VALUE
test is now set to TEST_VALUE
```

========================================================

**Option #2** 
*Based on the OP comment*

**default.json**

```
{
    "test":"TEST1"
}
```

**dev_config.json**

```
{
    "test":"TEST_VALUE"
}
```

**app.js**

```
DEFAULT_CONFIG = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ?
    require('./dev_config.json') :
    require('./default.json');
```

**Command line**

*To use dev_config.json config settings*

```
foo@bar:~$ NODE_ENV=dev node app.js
```

**or**

*To use regular default.json config settings*

```
foo@bar:~$ node app.js
```

Comment: but if i have multiple variable to set than i have to written this line of code for each variable

Comment: I do not know your exact usage case. Yes, you are correct... If you use this method I provided you would need to add more code to override and set configuration values via command line arguments.

Comment: my purpose is to use this in my project as i can able to change some variables value s which are changes according to environment from the external sources via other file or cmd or using environment variable

Comment: OK , i am updating my answer to better suit your need.

Comment: Please see my revise option #2 ... You can have a secondary config file that you will store your developer environment settings...